# Two candidates, A & B, are running for president. What is the probability that candidate A beats candidate B?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Candidate A has already garnered 80 votes.
Candidate B has already garnered 50 votes.

The number of votes a candidate must have in order to win the election is 115.
The votes of 5 states are still being counted. 
Winning a state gives a candidate 20 votes. Losing a state gives them no votes.

Assuming that both candidates have equal chances of winning those five states, what is the probability that candidate A will beat candidate B?

---

Procedure Taken:

1) Determine the number of ways in which A & B can get the votes that they need: Na and Nb.

- A needs 2 states to garner the required 35 votes. B needs 4 states to garner the required 65 votes.
- Na = summation from i=2..5 of (5 nCr i) = 26
- Nb = summation from i=4..5 of (5 nCr i) = 6

2) Determine the total number of outcomes, N, possible.

- N = 2^(5) = 32
- Where 2 is the win or lose outcome possibilities of each state.

3) Determine probabilities:

- P(A wins) = Na/N = 26/32 = .8125
- P(B wins) = Nb/N = 6/32 = .1875

---

The problem I have:

- In this solution, P(A wins) + P(B wins) = 1, which is intuitively pleasing.
- However, if B had 80 votes as well and only needed 35 votes to win, the procedure taken above would result in: P(A wins) = P(B wins) = .8125. This is not intuitively pleasing.

How do I fix my procedure?

Comment: To begin, by visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you can learn how to type mathematical formulae and equations such as $\sum\limits_{i=2}^5 \binom{5}{i}=26$.  Secondly, if $B$ also had $80$ votes to begin with, you should note that the winner will be determined after exactly three of the states send in their results.  The sample space and probabilities will both change.  Consider making a tree diagram instead of using a counting argument to convince yourself of the fact that $P(A)=P(B)=0.5$ in that case.

Comment: The original wording of the question seems off a bit.  Note that if $B$ wins three of the five remaining states and $A$ wins two of the five remaining states, the final total $B$ has will be $50+3\cdot 20 = 110>105$ and $A$ will end with $80+2\cdot 20 = 120>105$.  Both numbers will be greater than $105$, so who wins in this scenario?  Both of them or just $A$?  Or do the states send in their results at separate times and the winner is the *first* of them who go over $105$?

Comment: Oops it should be 115 is required to win, not 105! Good catch!

Comment: If both candidates had $80$ votes and need $115$ to win, then if A wins $2$ and B wins $3$ of the remaining states, both candidates win. If your assumptions allow the possibility of both candidates winning, why is it not intuitively pleasing that the probabilities add up to more than $1$?

Comment: Here's the thought: Let's say $$P(A win) = .8125$$. Thus $$P(A lose) = 1 - P (A win)$$. Then shouldn't $$P(A lose) = P(B win)$$?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ had $80$ votes each already, with five states ($20$ votes each) still undecided, there would be a total of $260$ votes to be cast in this election. To receive a majority of the votes would require at least $131$ votes, meaning it would not be enough to win two states; a candidate would have to win three.

If the *only* thing you change is that $B$ also has $80$ votes, so either $A$ or $B$ could still "win" with merely $115$ votes, it would be possible for both to "win" (whatever that means) under that rule. At least one would
have to win, however. Considering those facts, the sum of the individual
probabilities $P(A \text{ wins})$ and $P(B \text{ wins})$
would *have* to be greater than $1$.